# Easy app still crashes after being re-built

Tags: android

I'm learning how to write an Android App with Android Studio 2.3. Seems to be x100 harder than doing java. I want to write a String of three EditText´s into a .txt file. I know my variables are named very bad. The app ran very often without a crash after adding just some lines, just to check if the new button is there because i´m so suspiciously after crashes though i took back my last changes. Can´t be a solution to copy the Android Studio Project after every simple change which was unsuccessful.

```
package com.example.markus.myapplication3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArtHin extends Activity {
    Button ok;
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText editText3;
    public String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_art_hin);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        File dir = new File(path);
        dir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(path + "/bestand.txt");
    }

    public void buttonSave(View view){
        File file = new File(path + "/bestand.txt");
        String zeile = editText.getText().toString()+"@"+editText2.getText().toString()+">"+editText3.getText().toString();
        String [] transfer = zeile.split("");
        editText.setText("");
        editText2.setText("");
        editText3.setText("");
        Save (file, transfer);
}

public static void Save(File file, String[] data)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
            {
                fos.write(data[i].getBytes());
                if (i < data.length-1)
                {
                    fos.write("\n".getBytes());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
}
```

Error:

```
03-12 17:26:20.470 2306-2306/com.example.markus.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.markus.myapplication2/com.example.markus.myapplication.MainActivity2}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.markus.myapplication.MainActivity2" on path: /data/app/com.example.markus.myapplication2-1.apk
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.markus.myapplication.MainActivity2" on path: /data/app/com.example.markus.myapplication2-1.apk
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Need to include your crash log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.markus.myapplication.MainActivity2" on path

That isn't the name of the class you showed.

```
public class ArtHin extends Activity
```

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure your classes are actually correct.

Comment: That´s the activity when you open the app. By clicking a button you get to the ArtHin. Won´t surprise me if that´s a mistake of the third copy.

Comment: Your error is when you attempt to create a `MainActivity2`, and that just doesn't exist, according to your error. I was saying anything was wrong with `ArtHin` itself

Comment: MainActivity2 was the name of my third version. Don´t know why AS is running with that version. Now the APK was generated successfully but that´s no sign that the app doesn´t crash. It´s hard to fall in love with android programming :D Edit: You´re really fast. Great Community.

Comment: You probably were running over Instant Run and you removed/renamed an Activity. Cleaning and Rebuilding the project can fix those issues.

Comment: Solved so far! There was a MyApp2 where MyApp3 should be.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable **instant run** in your android studio from setting. And try to rebuild your app.
Android studio 2.3 have some issue with instant run.

Disable instant run:

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and **uncheck** Enable Instant Run.

I am facing same issue after updating android studio.

Comment: Now i get this message: 
IllegalStateException: Cannot locate factory for objects of type DefaultGradleConnector, as ConnectorServiceRegistry has been closed.
I´m sure there is an answer for that here